# listing specific files with prefix

Tags: php, html

Hi I would like to list all specific files with the prefix myfile-..

This is my current code... and no files are listed

```
   <select name="s1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
        <?php 
            foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/*') as $filename){
                $filename = basename($filename);
               // if (preg_match('/\.(php)$/i', $filename)) {
                    if (preg_grep('~^myfile-.*\.php$~', $filename)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

if I use this... all files are listed

```
 if (preg_match('/\.(php)$/i', $filename)) {
```

while no files are listed if using this

```
if (preg_grep('~^myfile-.*\.php$~', $filename)) {
```

Comment: Check the glob()-Function in the Manual.

Comment: why preg_grep, preg_grep is only for array while $filename is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest way:

```
foreach (glob(dirname(__FILE__)."myfile-*.php") as $filename) {
        echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make it so hard?

```
If(substr($filename, 0, 7) == "myfile-"){
    echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
```

Substr looks at the first seven characters and looks if it's "myfile-"

Comment: Why not use `glob()` to only return the matching files in the first place?

Comment: @Magnus I figured there was still a need for all filenames

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out..anyway..thank you all

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
        <?php 
           foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/myfile-*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: {} is just for or condition, you do not need {php} here, just use .php is fine. And so use my solution lol